# Converting ASP.NET WebForms project to MVC4 project

Tags: asp.net-mvc

We have approximately 900 aspx pages website (webforms). We need to convert them into mvc4 application.

Problem is that when we convert it to mvc4 then it need to convert in to form of webapplication and when it convert in to webapplication then it create multiple designer file into my project. and it fire the error that

Error   5   Type 'Admin_Page_List_World' already defines a member called 'Page_Load' with the same parameter types

This happened because the Admin_Page_List_World class is a partial class and it is defined in multiple places.

If I remove the particular class then it fires the error partial directive is used in another place. There are multiple entry.

So, can anyone explain or suggest what I can do to resolve this issue?

Comment: what is your way of converting (i.e. from aspx to cshtml)

Comment: simple I want to change aspx page from aspx to aspx I no need to razor engine or no need to cshtml page

Comment: you cannot just convert webforms to mvc by copying the aspx files, read https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991978.aspx

Comment: The .aspx extension mvc pages do not exist since MVC 2 - which was before razor engine was introduced. In other words if you want to use Razor you will have to adopt the .cshtml files and rewrite your code completely. On the other hand you can easily create a .NET project which runs both MVC and web forms pages and then covert your code as time permits. No need to convert everything right away.

Answer (score 0):

Are you converting everything into MVC in one shot?I would suggest a iterative approach. Convert the project into MVC and make sure the .aspx routes are ignored. Then slowly change pages one by one. One good link below.

http://blog.falafel.com/integrating-aspnet-mvc-4-into-existing-web-forms-applications/